# Base64 to tikz converter

Tags: tikz-pgf, inkscape

Actually, on can convert base64 to all kind of images (png,svg ...), but how to convert base64, png, svg to tikz now ?

There is no command to my knowledge that allows to embed base64 without running external command base64-d with --shell escape option. So the neetest option would be to have a method to convert images to tikz.

Inkscape add on to convert images to tikz does not work anymore with new versions of inkscape.

Comment: I don't really understand your last paragraph. Inkscape uses `svg2tikz` to convert images to tikz. This works still fine with the current version of inkscape.

Comment: If you want to display base64 images, have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/inline-images?lang=en

Comment: Such a thing could be implemented in Lua, perhaps.

Comment: @sam this package uses an external tool, hence requires `--shell-escape`.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your comments.

So for svg2tikz, the main [https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz][https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz],  package is not maintained but there is a pull request that works.

I could run

```
wget https://rviews.rstudio.com/css/images/rstudio.svg
pip install git+git://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz --user
svg2tikz --figonly rstudio.svg
```

For base64 to svg, I found it here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038824/decode-base64-svg-data-to-a-svg-file][1]